# python get active user in linux when 2 users are logged in

Tags: python, linux

I write python script that starts with desktop user session in Ubuntu Linux. It send some requests to server on external device signal. But if I change user in ubuntu (not logout first, but login second) - I get 2 requests to server with one device signal. I want to determine which user is in "active" desktop session and send request from this user only. How can I do it?

P.S. Script has minimal GUI for user, so I cannot run it as background service.